# Can I disable the div id linking with Jquery UI Tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-tabs

Here's a demo: http://up.videodetective.com/Jeff/strip/2/slider.html

It rotates every 5 seconds, now scroll to the bottom of the page and wait 5 seconds. When it goes to the next item in the slideshow the whole page bounces you up to where the div id is(in this case the top).

Which is a poor user experience in my opinion, is there a way to disable it from moving you where ever the div id is? I've looked online but couldn't find anything.

Oh and by the way I've only tested FF 3.6, Chrome, and IE9 so if there is CSS issues that you see a heads up would be great, but my main concern is the being brought up to the div id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your CCS rule for `#slider`, add

```
#slider {
    /*...*/
    height: 500px;
    /*...*/
}
```

Giving the slider a value for height will prevent the jump that happens when the inner elements get replaced.